# store variables to user session Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a 'roulette heatmap' application that I have been working with [URL REMOVED] just for a bit of fun.

It has a bunch of tiles (divs) with a value that gets incremented each time you select on a tile to track the spins on a roulette table. Is there a way to store the incremented numbers to a session so that if the page gets reloaded the variable values are not lost?

Much like the '2048 game' where you can move the tiles, leave the page and come back and it remembers your positions without being registered.

Comment: use cookies, or HTML5 local storage.

Comment: Yes there is.  I'm not clicking on your link, and without code, that's the best answer you're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of storing persistent data is using cookies.

Storing a cookie value

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

getting a previously stored cookie value

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

If you do decide to choose this method, I would suggest a [cookie viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-cookies/) to help out.